# Ishmael and Sacrifice

Tags: quran

The Wikipedia article on Ishmael and sacrifice says that "As Abraham attempts to slay Ishmael, either the knife is turned over in his hand or copper appears on Ishmael to prevent the death and God tells Abraham that he has fulfilled the command."
There is no reference in this story and I do not find this anywhere in the Koran, so could you tell me the source of the narrative?

Comment: Which part are you looking for a reference? The knife being turned over part?

Comment: I would appreciate knowing where both references are originating (knife turning over and the copper reference), but if you have one or the other I will take it. Thank you.

Comment: Has anyone made in progress in finding out these references?